# How to update the millisecond part of timestamp in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this, I need to update all millisecond value with zeros. How this can be achieved?

```
+-------------+-------------------------+
|     USER    |              DATE       |
+-------------+-------------------------+
| TEST        | 2020-02-20 19:19:16.130 |
| TEST        | 2020-02-20 19:19:31.113 |
+-------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Please edit your question to tag which DBMS you're using and include any code attempts you've made so far.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres you can do this using `date_trunc()`

```
update the_table
  set date = date_trunc('second', date);
```

In Oracle you can cast it to a timestamp without milliseconds

```
update the_table
  set date = cast(date as timestamp(0));
```

(The above is actually standard ANSI SQL and would work in Postgres as well)

Comment: This worked.
`update the_table
  set date = cast(date as datetime2(0));`